# How to drop observations after a certain condition is met in R

Tags: r, subset

I have the following situation:

```
      vertex Time Adopt time_adopt
         1    1     0          0
         2    1     0          0
         3    1     0          0
        *4    1     1          1*
         5    1     0          0
         1    2     0          0
        *2    2     1          2*
         3    2     0          0
         4    2     1          2
         5    2     0          0
```

I would like to drop all observations/vertex once they met the condition Adopt==1. In other words, in this short sample vertex 6, 9 and 20 have Adopt==1, this means that I don't want to have them in Time>1 anymore, and so on for all other vertex dynamically. For example, in the first table, the highlighted vertex 4 have Adopt==1 in time 1 and vertex 2 have Adopt==1 in time 2. Following the above sample I would like to obtain the following i.e. vertex 4 not present in time 2 (that is a time after he has adopt==1) and vertex 2 not present in time 3. And so on for all vertexes once they get "infected" (Adopt==1):

```
      vertex Time Adopt time_adopt
         1    1     0          0
         2    1     0          0
         3    1     0          0
         4    1     1          1
         5    1     0          0
         1    2     0          0
        *2    2     1          2*
         3    2     0          0
         5    2     0          0
         1    3     0          0
         3    3     0          0
         5    3     0          0
```

How can I implement this conditional selection in R?

Thanks all

Comment: have you tried: dataframe %>% filter(time_adopt != 1)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to keep rows for each vertex up until the first `time` point where they have `Adopt == 1`, but then you want to exclude those vertexes from subsequent `Time`s? If so, maybe you should edit your example to illustrate that problem - instead of 15 vertexes at 1 timepoint, create an example with 5 vertexes at 3 timepoints, and show the desired output for the sample input.

Comment: Sorry, just edit to make it clearer. Yes, I want to keep rows up untile they have Adopt==1 whatever the Time is. From that Time point, not have these rows anymore for subsequent times.

Comment: Still don't get it. I can't actually see which rows got dropped and why. Maybe try highlighting exactly which rows you want to drop in the before and after?

Comment: Each row needs to be drop once the vertex move from Adopt=0 to Adopt==1. Once he reaches the status 1 I don't want to see it anymore in subsequent times. In the example, vertex 4 has Adopt==1 in time==1, so I don't want it anymore in time==2. I hope to be clear now, and sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  filter(Adopt != 1)
```

Comment: In this case I will have only Adopt==0, but I want to keep those Adopt==1 in the Time they have value 1. I updated the questions to make it clearer, sorry if I wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple to solve using `mutate` from the dplyr library.

```
library(dplyr)
time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
adopt <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
df <- data.frame(time, adopt)

df %>% mutate(time_adopt=time*adopt)
```

And by slightly modifying the mutate function you can also query for any value in adopt w/o relying on it being 1 for multiplication.

```
library(dplyr)
time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
adopt <- c(1,0,5,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
df <- data.frame(time, adopt)

df %>% mutate(time_adopt = (adopt == 5)*time)
```

Comment: I already have time_adopt variable, this is not the problem. The point is how to drop observations for subsequent times once they reached the status Adopt==1